# Sub procidure errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having errors when running a program for counting ice skating scores
the errors are as followed when running in python 3.7.0
[Errors when loading in python 3.7.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6C0L.png)
. Any help appreciated thank you

Here is the task I was given and I am required to use def and sub procedures:

> Program 1
>
> A program is to be written to process scores by competitors in an
>   ice-skating competition.  Each skater receives a score in the range
>   0.0-6.0 from each of the 6 judges.  A skater’s overall score is calculated from the total of the 6 scores minus the best and the worst
>   scores.
>
> Create a modular program which makes use of parameter passing to
>   implement the specification above.

```
def get_scores(score,totalscore,checknumber):
loops = 0
for loops in range(0,6):
    checknumber = validatescore(checknumber)
    score[loops]=float(checknumber)

maxi = find_max(score)
mini = find_min(score)
totalscore = totalscore + calculate_score(score,totalscore,maxi,mini)

return score[loops],totalscore,checknumber

def find_min(score):
min = 100
for counter in range (0,len(score)):
    if score[counter] < min: 
        mini = score[counter]
    return mini

 def find_max(score):
    max = 100
     for counter in range (0,6):
        if score[counter] < max: 
            maxi = score[counter]
    return maxi

def calculate_score(score,totalscore,maxi,mini):
    for loops in range(0,6):
        totalscore = totalscore + score[loops]
    totalscore = totalscore - maxi - mini
    return totalscore,maxi,mini

def displaydetails (totalscore,maxi,mini):
    print("The competitor scored: ",totalscore, "The max was :",maxi," The min was :",mini)

def validatescore(checknumber):
    valid = False
    checknumber = 0
    print("Please enter the score of the competitor")
    checknumber = float(input())
    while valid == False:
        if checknumber < 0.0 or checknumber > 6.0:
            print("Invalid mark - please enter a whole number between 0.0 and 6.0")
            checknumber = float(input())
        else:
             valid = True
    return checknumber



totalscore = 0.0
score = [0.0] * 6
checknumber = 0.0


score,totalscore,checknumber = get_scores(score,totalscore,checknumber)

displaydetails(totalscore,maxi,mini)
```

Comment: `calculate_score` returns a tuple which you are trying to add to a float value. Also, could you fix the indentation in your code and copy and paste the error message in the question, don't post screenshots